# Stopping a task and resuming it with more allocated cores

Tags: process

Is it possible to start a task eg-

```
$ make xxx
```

then pause it, and resume it with more cores allocated?

```
$ <some-resume-command> <pid> -j
```

which would be the equivalent of switching to the below command

```
$ make -j xxx
```